# Composite key, in comparison

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hql

I have three fields that form a unique composite key on a table.

I want to pass in 3 different arrays, where the index matches.

```
custIds= [0,1,2]
custLetters = [A,B,C]
products = ["Cheese","lemons","Aubergine"]
```

is there one sql statement that will return all three rows (assuming they exists), 
just combining via `in` won't work to due to "false positives" :

```
select * from mytable 
where custId in (custIds)
 and custLetters in (custLetters)
and product in (products);
```

database oracle, but via hibernate hql, so ansi preferred if possible ?

Comment: It is possible with `hibernate criteria` if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OT: your SQL query is probably wrong. It should be:

```
select * from mytable 
where (custId, custLetters, product) 
in ( (0, 'A', 'Cheese'),
 (1, 'B', 'lemons'),
 (2, 'C', 'Aubergine'));
```

I'm not use whether Hibernate can generate such a query. But `in` is just a syntax sugar for conjuctions and disjunctions.

Comment: `Hibernate HQL` is same as SQL query.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli it is similar, but there are many differences. It is definitely not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could compose your arrays into a single one, after that:

```
custIds= [0,1,2]
custLetters = [A,B,C]
products = ["Cheese","lemons","Aubergine"]

Key=["0ACheese","1Blemons","2CAubergine"]

select * from mytable 
where custId+custLetters+product in (Key);
```

Comment: How would this work if there was an existing record of custid = 1, custletter = A, and products = lemons?

Comment: @DanBrauck it wouldn't, but thats not the question. A rather hacky solution, but would work +1

Comment: No it would not work because `custId+custLetters+product` is invalid SQL. The concatenation operator for characters is `||` the `+` sign is for numbers.