# Composite key query using HQL and separate IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a hibernate entity defined with a composite key, using id class and id annoation on columns. Works fine.  However I now want to do a [composite key query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084730/106261).

```
Select mt 
from MyTable mt 
where (mt.id, mt.column2) in (:myListOfCompositeKeys)
```

What is the syntax using HQL, when I have defined the entity like below (not using embeddedId).

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyKey.class)
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Column2")
    @Id
    private Long column2;
```

Or do I need to use `embeddedId` and if so what would be the `HQL` syntax for that ?

Comment: if you do entityManager.find(entityClass, id); with the type if id =  MyKey this will do it.

Comment: @nicearma restricted to HQL unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [@EmbededId](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-embeddedid-example/), you will have to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods and HQL for it would be something like below.

```
SELECT mt
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE mt.id 
IN(:listOfKeys)
```